# round up on script function

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have code like this

```
<script>
    function startCalc(){
        interval = setInterval("calc()",1);}
    function calc()
    {
        plfnd       = document.myForm.plfnd.value;

        apk         = document.myForm.apk.value         = (plfnd / jkw);
                }
```

and i want to round up apk. i tried to use code like this 
`apk        = document.myForm.apk.value         = Math.round10((plfnd / jkw),-3);` 
and nothing happen. can anyone help to solve my problem?

Comment: There's no math method called `round10`. There is [`round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), however.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yeah i forgot to describe Math.round10

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Math.round10` is not exists in your code. 
Try to copy this part to your script:

```
    if (!Math.round10) {
        Math.round10 = function (value, exp) {
          exp = exp;
          value = value.toString().split('e');
          value = Math['round'](+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp)));
          value = value.toString().split('e');
          return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp));
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks forget to describe Math.round10